# windowSoftInputMode=“adjustResize” doesn't work in my Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have form-like editTexts and my `softkeyboard` is overlapping `editText` field. In my `FragmentActivity` I just set `windowSoftInputMode=“adjustResize”` in my `AndroidManifest` (or in `onCreate()`) and it works. But in my regular Activity I set this and it doesnt work at all.

I cant set `android:fitsystemwindow="true"` because it will destroy my layout with transparent `statusBar` and not transparent `navigationBar`.

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".ProfilePackage.EditProfile.EditProfileActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: Try putting up the layout in `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activities.CommentActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

I had the same Problem where the Softkeyboard was covering other views. So I added this line in manifest.